# Slider Revolution problems with missing pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, graphics

I'm using Slider Revolution as a front page slider. I'm trying out some new images on the slider, but they all themes to vanish...

```
        <div class="tp-banner-container">
        <div class="tp-banner">
            <ul>
                <!-- SLIDE Main -->
                <li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1500">
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="~/Img/fpslider/slider1.png" alt=" slidebg1" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <!-- LAYERS -->
                    <div class="tp-caption fade"
                         data-x="130"
                         data-y="center"
                         data-speed="800"
                         data-start="1500"
                         data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
                         data-endspeed="300"
                         data-endeasing="Linear.easeNone"
                         data-captionhidden="off">
                        <img src="~/Img/fpslider/slider11.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- LAYERS NR. 2 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption lfr large_text"
                         data-x="500"
                         data-y="120"
                         data-speed="1500"
                         data-start="2000"
                         data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
                         data-endspeed="300"
                         data-endeasing="Linear.easeNone"
                         data-captionhidden="off">
                        Velkommen til
                    </div>
                    <!-- LAYERS NR. 2.1 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption lfr very_large_text"
                         data-x="500"
                         data-y="150"
                         data-speed="1500"
                         data-start="2300"
                         data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
                         data-endspeed="300"
                         data-endeasing="Linear.easeNone"
                         data-captionhidden="off">
                        Seduc
                    </div>
                </li>
```

etc...

The images are a png 24 as transparent...

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone seen this problem before? I could not Google it...

Comment: It seems to work on iPhone.. It looks stranges in IE..

Comment: In Mozilla and Safari the problem is there..